# optimizing Chrome speed using flag "GPU rasterization MSAA sample count" 2 cores, 4 logical processors. Should I choose 2 or 4?

Tags: google-chrome, performance, gpu, cpu-cores, logical-processor

I'm running Windows 10 Home x64, and have an Intel Core i5-5200u, CPU @ 2.20GHz, with 8G RAM. I'm playing around with tweaking Chrome for optimal speed, and have found adjusting some flags quite helpful, but I'm not certain what numerical value I should choose for the "GPU rasterization MSAA sample count" (chrome://flags/#gpu-rasterization-msaa-sample-count)? Process Lasso shows four cores, but upon reading further, it looks like I only have two physical cores... and the other two are logical cores?

Could someone let me know whether I should pick 2 or 4? It seems as though (although this is entirely subjective) 4 slows down Chrome, so I'm leaning toward 2. Again, this is to optimize Chrome (newest beta: 53.0.2785.57 beta-m (64-bit)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the number of `gpu-rasterization-msaa-sample-count` will put more load on your GPU. If you're looking to speed up Chrome, setting this value to 0 will yield the highest performance benefit. The number of cores, physical or logical, that your CPU has will not have an impact.

This setting is only used if the `enable-gpu-rasterization` flag is also enabled.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I couldn't find that anywhere else. :)